# Updating seekbar from Service

Tags: android, service, seekbar, audio-player, android-music-player

I am building a music player and i need to add a seekbar for the songs. I have checked online but most of the results are for a media player that is in an activity as opposed to a service. I am new to using the media player so any detailed results would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you familiar with "bound services"? this is a good example when you can use a "bound local service" pattern

Comment: I've been reading up on it and trying a few implementations but i havent gotten it to work yet.

Comment: did you try "bound local service" pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Broadcast Receiver to send data from service to activity.

Add Below Method in Service and call this method whenever you want to update `SeekBar`.

```
public static void publishResult(Context context, int percentage){
    Intent intent = new Intent("Broadcast");
    intent.putExtra("INTENT_TYPE", "SEEKBAR_RESULT");
    intent.putExtra("PERCENTAGE", 10);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

In Activity Add Following Code To Receive the broadcast messages.

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Register Broadcast receiver 
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("Broadcast"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Unregister Broadcast receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String intentType = intent.getStringExtra("INTENT_TYPE");
            if(intentType.equalsIgnoreCase("SEEKBAR_RESULT")){
                int percentage = intent.getIntExtra("PERCENTAGE");
            }
        }
    };
```

For more detail on LocalBroadcastManager Refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

Comment: What about when the activity isnt on the foreground? How will the seekbar update to the correct position when the activity it resumed?

Comment: @AlexKombo that's a valid question. You can store the result in Application Global variable or in Shared-preference and on Resume method you can update the seekbar. And for foreground activity you can use Broadcast receiver to update the Seekbar.

Comment: @AlexKombo Happy to help you. :-)

Comment: `"What about when the activity isnt on the foreground?"` that is why i said to use a "bound" service, in this case when no activity is bound to your service, noone is notified about the change, once an activity binds to your service it it directly notified

Comment: @DhavalPatel yes i read it and this is not a way anybody should follow, just use a "bound service", really

Comment: @pskink I think it depend upon the scenario. For music player like app "startService" fits more then "bound service". because bound service can't run independently from activity. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @DhavalPatel yes you are wrong, you can have both started and bound service, see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/bound-services.html) ^F `Binding to a Started Service`

Comment: @pskink I think you should write an answer to this question.